# Change user name

Tags: terminal, books

I had to change the admin user name of a new Macbook because his sons name kept showing up, Home Folder etc, So I used, 
'`sudo mv /Users/oldusername /Users/newusername`'
and Advanced Options in User account.

Now this has worked very well apart from iBooks!
iBooks still has the 'oldusername' in it's path.

Don't know what I've done wrong!!!

`sudo mv /Users/oldname/Library/Containers?com.apple.BKAgentService?Data?Documents?ibooks/books/ Users/newname/Library/Containers?com.apple.BKAgentService?Data?Documents?ibooks/books`

Would this work ?, I am not very good with terminal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The command should be:

```
$sudo mv /Users/oldname/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/ibooks/books  /Users/newname/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/ibooks/books
```

This is assuming that there was not an existing user "newname" with it's own uid. Then you may run into permissions problems.

Hope this helps!